# Looking way to refactor these two methods into single method

Tags: c#, .net, generics, refactoring, c#-6.0

Hi All i am trying to generate the word document with two different tables included in it, for this purpose i have two similar methods where i am passing word document reference and data object and table to the similar  methods..

Now i am looking to make single method in generic way so that in different places i can use single method by passing parameters to it

**Method 1 :**

```
    private static List<OpenXmlElement> RenderExhaustEquipmentTableDataAndNotes(MainDocumentPart mainDocumentPart, List<ProjectObject<ExhaustEquipment>> exhaustEquipment,Table table)
    {
        HtmlConverter noteConverter = new HtmlConverter(mainDocumentPart);
        var equipmentExhaustTypes = new Dictionary<string, List<ProjectObject<ExhaustEquipment>>>();

        foreach (var item in exhaustEquipment)
        {
            string exhaustEquipmentName = item.TargetObject.Name;
            if (!equipmentExhaustTypes.ContainsKey(exhaustEquipmentName))
            {
                equipmentExhaustTypes.Add(exhaustEquipmentName, new List<ProjectObject<ExhaustEquipment>>());
            }
            equipmentExhaustTypes[exhaustEquipmentName].Add(item);
        }

        List<OpenXmlElement> notes = new List<OpenXmlElement>();
        int noteIndex = 1;
        foreach (var exhaustEquipmentItem in equipmentExhaustTypes)
        {
            List<string> noteIndices = new List<string>();
            for (int exhaustEquipmentConditionIndex = 0; exhaustEquipmentConditionIndex < exhaustEquipmentItem.Value.Count; exhaustEquipmentConditionIndex++)
            {
                var condition = exhaustEquipmentItem.Value[exhaustEquipmentConditionIndex];
                var row = new TableRow();
                Run superscriptRun = new Run(new RunProperties(new VerticalTextAlignment { Val = VerticalPositionValues.Superscript }));

                if (exhaustEquipmentConditionIndex == 0)
                {              
                    row.Append(RenderOpenXmlElementContentCell(new Paragraph(
                        new List<Run> {
                            new Run(new RunProperties(), new Text(exhaustEquipmentItem.Key) { Space = SpaceProcessingModeValues.Preserve }),
                            superscriptRun
                        }), 1,
                        new OpenXmlElement[] {new VerticalMerge { Val = MergedCellValues.Restart },new TableCellMargin {
                                LeftMargin = new LeftMargin { Width = "120" },
                                TopMargin = new TopMargin { Width = "80" } }
                        }));
                }
                else
                {
                    row.Append(RenderTextContentCell(null, 1, null, null, new OpenXmlElement[] { new VerticalMerge { Val = MergedCellValues.Continue } }));
                }
                row.Append(RenderTextContentCell(condition.TargetObject.IsConstantVolume ? "Yes" : "No"));
                row.Append(RenderTextContentCell($"{condition.TargetObject.MinAirflow:R2}"));
                row.Append(RenderTextContentCell($"{condition.TargetObject.MaxAirflow:R2}"));

                if (condition.TargetObject.NotesHTML?.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (var note in condition.TargetObject.NotesHTML)
                    {
                        var compositeElements = noteConverter.Parse(note);
                        var htmlRuns = compositeElements.First().ChildElements.Where(c => c is Run).Cast<Run>().Select(n => n.CloneNode(true));
                        notes.Add(new Run(htmlRuns));
                        noteIndices.Add(noteIndex++.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
                    }
                }                   
                if (exhaustEquipmentConditionIndex == exhaustEquipmentItem.Value.Count - 1 && condition.TargetObject.NotesHTML?.Count > 0)
                {
                    superscriptRun.Append(new Text($"({String.Join(',', noteIndices)})") { Space = SpaceProcessingModeValues.Preserve });
                }
                table.Append(row);
            }
        }
        List<OpenXmlElement> notesSection = new List<OpenXmlElement>();
        List<OpenXmlElement> result = RenderNotesArray(table, notes, notesSection);
        return result;
    }
```

and I am calling this method like this in below

```
 var table = new Table(RenderTableProperties());
 table.Append(new TableRow(
                    RenderTableHeaderCell("Name"),
                    RenderTableHeaderCell("Constant Volume"),
                    RenderTableHeaderCell("Minimum Airflow", units: "(cfm)"),
                    RenderTableHeaderCell("Wet Bulb Temperature", units: "(cfm)")
                    ));
body.Append(RenderExhaustEquipmentTableDataAndNotes(mainDocumentPart, designHubProject.ExhaustEquipment, table));
```

**Method 2:**

```
    private static List<OpenXmlElement> RenderInfiltrationTableData(MainDocumentPart mainDocumentPart, List<ProjectObject<Infiltration>> infiltration,Table table)
    {
        HtmlConverter noteConverter = new HtmlConverter(mainDocumentPart);
        var nameByInflitrationObject = new Dictionary<string, List<ProjectObject<Infiltration>>>();

        foreach (var infiltrationData in infiltration)
        {
            string infiltrationName = infiltrationData.TargetObject.Name;
            if (!nameByInflitrationObject.ContainsKey(infiltrationName))
            {
                nameByInflitrationObject.Add(infiltrationName, new List<ProjectObject<Infiltration>>());
            }
            nameByInflitrationObject[infiltrationName].Add(infiltrationData);
        }

        List<OpenXmlElement> notes = new List<OpenXmlElement>();
        int noteIndex = 1;

        foreach (var inflitrationDataItem in nameByInflitrationObject)
        {
            List<string> noteIndices = new List<string>();
            for (int inflitrationNameIndex = 0; inflitrationNameIndex < inflitrationDataItem.Value.Count; inflitrationNameIndex++)
            {
                var dataItem = inflitrationDataItem.Value[inflitrationNameIndex];
                var row = new TableRow();
                Run superscriptRun = new Run(new RunProperties(new VerticalTextAlignment { Val = VerticalPositionValues.Superscript }));

                if (inflitrationNameIndex == 0)
                {
                    row.Append(RenderOpenXmlElementContentCell(new Paragraph(
                        new List<Run> {
                            new Run(new RunProperties(), new Text(inflitrationDataItem.Key) { Space = SpaceProcessingModeValues.Preserve }),superscriptRun
                        }), 1,
                        new OpenXmlElement[] {new VerticalMerge { Val = MergedCellValues.Restart },new TableCellMargin {
                                LeftMargin = new LeftMargin { Width = "120" },
                                TopMargin = new TopMargin { Width = "80" }}
                        }));
                }
                else
                {
                    row.Append(RenderTextContentCell(null, 1, null, null, new OpenXmlElement[] { new VerticalMerge { Val = MergedCellValues.Continue } }));
                }
                row.Append(RenderTextContentCell($"{dataItem.TargetObject.AirflowScalar.ToString("R2", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)} cfm {EnumUtils.StringValueOfEnum(dataItem.TargetObject.InfiltrationCalculationType).ToLower(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)}"));

                if (dataItem.TargetObject.NotesHTML?.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (var note in dataItem.TargetObject.NotesHTML)
                    {
                        var compositeElements = noteConverter.Parse(note);
                        var htmlRuns = compositeElements.First().ChildElements.Where(c => c is Run).Cast<Run>().Select(n => n.CloneNode(true));
                        notes.Add(new Run(htmlRuns));
                        noteIndices.Add(noteIndex++.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
                    }
                }

                if (inflitrationNameIndex == inflitrationDataItem.Value.Count - 1 && dataItem.TargetObject.NotesHTML?.Count > 0)
                {
                    superscriptRun.Append(new Text($"({String.Join(',', noteIndices)})") { Space = SpaceProcessingModeValues.Preserve });
                }
                table.Append(row);
            }
        }
        List<OpenXmlElement> notesSection = new List<OpenXmlElement>();
        List<OpenXmlElement> result = RenderNotesArray(table, notes, notesSection);
        return result;
    }
```

and then i am calling this method here like as below

```
   var table = new Table(RenderTableProperties());
   table.Append(new TableRow(
                    RenderTableHeaderCell("Type"),
                    RenderTableHeaderCell("Air Flow")
                    ));
   body.Append(RenderInfiltrationTableData(mainDocumentPart, designHubProject.Infiltration, table));
```

i know these are lots of lines but is there any generic way to use single method out of these two similar methods and i am using .net core

Could any one please suggest any idea or suggestion how can i refactor these two methods into single method that would be very grateful.

many thanks in advance

Comment: Frankly a method should do ONE single thing and one thing only - you might actually consider making multiple methods for each of the parts those two are doing.

Comment: the difference between these two methods are dataObject like `designHubProject.Infiltration, designHubProject.ExhaustEquipment`, table configuration passing to these methods and data appending to the row

Comment: Make a generic method

Comment: Break out the `foreach` unique body parts to be a lambda passed in and create three methods - the generic core method, and two type specific callers that pass in the lambda.

Comment: thanks for the advice, it would be great if you could provide any pseudo code for this one

Comment: @Nkosi could you please provide any sample code on this

Comment: consider https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @EnigmaState I'm only guessing but you're asking for something that from a quick glance seems to go against most coding practices.  The answer below is more along the lines of what would be a good refactoring - extracting methods so each method is doing one thing and then combining them in some way to achieve what you're after.

Comment: While I can understand that you may not find my answer sufficient, I don't know that any answer to such a question _can_ be **canonical**.

Comment: I have changed your answer a quite bit to suit to my approach, but still i am having noteindices problem

Comment: I started counting at `1` see where the issue is. I'll update the `Enumerable.Range(1, ` to `Enumerable.Range(0, ` in my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before we can create a single function that handles both types, achieving the highly laudable goal of removing gratuitous duplication, we should clean the code up to make it easier to see which parts, if any, are different between the two nearly identical methods.  And there is a lot to clean up, even if we only had one function.

In short, your functions are too long, having too much much code in one place, and in fact too much code altogether.
In the following, the original code has been broken down into multiple functions with specific purposes and refactored to remove DIY nonsense in favor of the standard library functions and the removal of pointless code.

```
static IEnumerable<OpenXmlElement> RenderExhaustEquipmentTableDataAndNotes(MainDocumentPart mainDocumentPart, List<ProjectObject<ExhaustEquipment>> exhaustEquipment, Table table)
{
    var equipmentByType = exhaustEquipment.ToLookup(item => item.TargetObject.Name);

    List<OpenXmlElement> notes = new List<OpenXmlElement>();

    foreach (var items in equipmentByType)
    {
        Run superscriptRun = CreateSuperScriptRun();

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            var row = new TableRow();

            if (item == items.First())
            {
                row.Append(CreateFirstRowStartingCell(items.Key, superscriptRun));
            }
            else
            {
                row.Append(RenderTextContentCell(null, 1, null, null, new[] {
                    new VerticalMerge { Val = MergedCellValues.Continue }
                }));
            }
            row.Append(RenderTextContentCell(item.TargetObject.IsConstantVolume ? "Yes" : "No"));
            row.Append(RenderTextContentCell($"{item.TargetObject.MinAirflow:R2}"));
            row.Append(RenderTextContentCell($"{item.TargetObject.MaxAirflow:R2}"));

            table.Append(row);

            var itemNotes = ParseNotes(mainDocumentPart, item.TargetObject.NotesHTML);

            if (item == items.Last() && itemNotes.Any())
            {
                UpdateSuperScript(superscriptRun, itemNotes);
            }

            notes.AddRange(itemNotes);
        }
    }
    List<OpenXmlElement> result = RenderNotesArray(table, notes, new List<OpenXmlElement>());
    return result;
}

private static Run CreateSuperScriptRun()
{
    return new Run(new RunProperties(new VerticalTextAlignment
    {
        Val = VerticalPositionValues.Superscript
    }));
}

private static void UpdateSuperScript(Run superscriptRun, IEnumerable<OpenXmlElement> notes)
{
    superscriptRun.Append(new Text($"({string.Join(",", Enumerable.Range(0, notes.Count()))})")
    {
        Space = SpaceProcessingModeValues.Preserve
    });
}

private static IEnumerable<OpenXmlElement> ParseNotes(MainDocumentPart mainDocumentPart, IEnumerable<OpenXmlElement> notes)
{
    return notes == null 
        ? Enumerable.Empty<OpenXmlElement>()
        : notes.Select(note => new HtmlConverter(mainDocumentPart).Parse(note))
               .Select(note => note.First().ChildElements
               .OfType<Run>()
               .Select(n => n.CloneNode(true))).Select(htmlRuns => new Run(htmlRuns))
               .ToList();
}


private OpenXmlElement CreateFirstRowStartingCell(string key, Run superscriptRun)
{
    return RenderOpenXmlElementContentCell(
        new Paragraph(new List<Run> {
        new Run(new RunProperties(), new Text(key) { Space = SpaceProcessingModeValues.Preserve }),
            superscriptRun
        }),
        1,
        new OpenXmlElement[] {
            new VerticalMerge { Val = MergedCellValues.Restart },
            new TableCellMargin { LeftMargin = new LeftMargin { Width = "120" }, TopMargin = new TopMargin { Width = "80" } }
        });
}
```

Now, let's tackle the second function:

```
static IEnunumerable<OpenXmlElement> RenderInfiltrationTableData(MainDocumentPart mainDocumentPart, IEnunumerable<ProjectObject<Infiltration>> infiltration, Table table)
{
    var infiltrationsByType = infiltration.ToLookup(item => item.TargetObject.Name);

    List<OpenXmlElement> notes = new List<OpenXmlElement>();

    foreach (var inflitrations in infiltrationsByType)
    {
        Run superscriptRun = CreateSuperScriptRun();

        foreach (var item in inflitrations)
        {
            var row = new TableRow();

            if (item == inflitrations.First())
            {
                row.Append(CreateFirstRowStartingCell(inflitrations.Key, superscriptRun));
            }
            else
            {
                row.Append(RenderTextContentCell(null, 1, null, null, new[] {
                    new VerticalMerge { Val = MergedCellValues.Continue }
                }));
            }
            row.Append(RenderTextContentCell($"{item.TargetObject.AirflowScalar:R2} cfm {item.TargetObject.InfiltrationCalculationType}").ToLower());

            table.Append(row);

            var itemNotes = ParseNotes(mainDocumentPart, item.TargetObject.NotesHTML);

            if (item == inflitrations.Last() && itemNotes.Any())
            {
                UpdateSuperScript(superscriptRun, itemNotes);
            }

            notes.AddRange(itemNotes);
        }
    }
    IEnumerable<OpenXmlElement> result = RenderNotesArray(table, notes, new List<OpenXmlElement>());
    return result;
}
```

As we have seen, duplication can be massively reduced simply by extracting code into simple helper functions.

This also makes it far easier to see just where the differences are between the two functions.

It is simply a matter of

```
row.Append(RenderTextContentCell(item.TargetObject.IsConstantVolume ? "Yes" : "No"));
row.Append(RenderTextContentCell($"{item.TargetObject.MinAirflow:R2}"));
row.Append(RenderTextContentCell($"{item.TargetObject.MaxAirflow:R2}"));
```

vs.

```
row.Append(RenderTextContentCell($"{item.TargetObject.AirflowScalar:R2} cfm {item.TargetObject.InfiltrationCalculationType}").ToLower());
```

To achieve your desired goal of a single function, we can make a generic function, and require that the caller pass in a function that will take care of these differences.

```
static IEnumerable<OpenXmlElement> RenderTableDataAndNotes<T>(
    MainDocumentPart mainDocumentPart,
    IEnumerable<ProjectObject<T>> projects,
    Table table,
    Func<ProjectObject<T>, IEnumerable<OpenXmlElement>> createCells
) where T : ITargetObject
{
    var projectsByType = projects.ToLookup(item => item.TargetObject.Name);
    List<OpenXmlElement> notes = new List<OpenXmlElement>();

    foreach (var items in projectsByType)
    {
        Run superscriptRun = CreateSuperScriptRun();

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            var row = new TableRow();

            if (item == items.First())
            {
                row.Append(CreateFirstRowStartingCell(items.Key, superscriptRun));
            }
            else
            {
                row.Append(RenderTextContentCell(null, 1, null, null, new[] {
                    new VerticalMerge { Val = MergedCellValues.Continue }
                }));
            }
            var itemCells = createCells(item);

            foreach (var cell in itemCells)
            {
                row.Append(cell);
            }

            table.Append(row);

            var itemNotes = ParseNotes(mainDocumentPart, item.TargetObject.NotesHTML);

            if (item == items.Last() && itemNotes.Any())
            {
                UpdateSuperScript(superscriptRun, itemNotes);
            }

            notes.AddRange(itemNotes);
        }
    }
    IEnumerable<OpenXmlElement> result = RenderNotesArray(table, notes, new List<OpenXmlElement>());
    return result;
}
```

Now, when we call it for say some Exhaust Equipment, we do so as follows:

```
 var rendered = RenderTableDataAndNotes(mainDocumentPart, exhaustProjects, table,
     exhaust => new[] {
         RenderTextContentCell(exhaust.TargetObject.IsConstantVolume ? "Yes" : "No"),
         RenderTextContentCell($"{exhaust.TargetObject.MinAirflow:R2}"),
         RenderTextContentCell($"{exhaust.TargetObject.MaxAirflow:R2}"),
  });
```

And for infiltration projects, we would do as follows:

```
var rendered = RenderTableDataAndNotes(
    mainDocumentPart,
    infiltrationProjects,
    table,
    infiltration => new[] {
        RenderTextContentCell($"{item.TargetObject.AirflowScalar:R2} cfm {item.TargetObject.InfiltrationCalculationType}")
     .ToLower()
});
```

The code could still be substantially improved even now. Currently it requires that the various project types implement a common `ITargetObject` interface declaring the `Name` property used to group projects by type. If you refactored your code to reduce nesting by hoisting `Name` to the `ProjectObject<T>` type, then we could remove the constraint and the otherwise useless requirement that `Infiltration`  and `ExhaustEquipment` implement the `ITargetObject` interface.

Note, if you can't change the types, you can adjust the code in a few ways.

For example, you can remove the type constraint on `T` and build the lookup outside and pass it to the function:

```
static IEnumerable<OpenXmlElement> RenderTableDataAndNotes<T>(
    MainDocumentPart mainDocumentPart,
    ILookup<string, ProjectObject<T>> projectsByType,
    Table table,
    Func<ProjectObject<T>, IEnumerable<OpenXmlElement>> createCells
)
```

Then you would call it as

```
var infiltrationProjectsByType = infiltrationProjects.ToLookup(project => project.Name);

var rendered = RenderTableDataAndNotes(
    mainDocumentPart,
    infiltrationProjectsByType,
    table,
    infiltration => new[] {
        RenderTextContentCell($"{infiltration.TargetObject.AirflowScalar:R2} cfm {infiltration.TargetObject.InfiltrationCalculationType}").ToLower()
    }
);
```

Comment: thanks for the inputs, unfortunately those two objects are not implemented interface and i cannot change the structure now. I am looking for single method extraction and where we can pass lambda function and other parameters into it so that we can use single method for both types

Comment: @EnigmaState, I added an alternative at the bottom that doesn't require implementing an interface or declaring a new member.

Comment: thanks for the modification, sorry to say i am still looking for single function from top to bottom where we can pass this row render from parent method

Comment: You object to breaking functions down into smaller functions?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, no i would like to use to single method where can i able to pass `MainDocumentPart mainDocumentPart, List<ProjectObject<Element>> element, Table table` and lambda function if possible to render that specific table cells

Comment: That is what my implementation does.

Comment: sorry it's little bit confusing because of more extraction

Comment: Well, take it, improve it, or leave it. However, I simplified your code, reducing the number of variables, minimizing mutable state, and removing code that was not needed. If you find it more readable with everything inlined, you can easily do that yourself, just cut and paste, but long functions are harder to read. I am sure there is room for further improvement.

Comment: sorry i am getting error at here `var rendered = RenderTableDataAndNotes(
                        mainDocumentPart,
                        infiltrationProjectsByType,
                        table,
                        infiltration => new[] {
        RenderTextContentCell($"{item.TargetObject.AirflowScalar.ToString("R2", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)} cfm {item.TargetObject.InfiltrationCalculationType}").ToLower(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
                        }
                    );` near by `item`

Comment: I renamed a parameter for clarity in the example but I missed a spot. `item` should be `infiltration`. I'll fix example

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215473/discussion-between-enigma-state-and-aluan-haddad).

Comment: i am fixing all issues one by one i have one more left and i implemented your code as well

Comment: I updated my question  with the image where that superscript count is starting from `1` for the second row where as it should start from `2` that is only issue right now i am having